# Conectar Median SSH usando node

Tags: javascript, nodejs, ssh

mi duda es si hay alguna forma de conectarme mediante SSH  a un servidor (namecheap) ejecutar un comando dentro de ese servidor y almacenar la respuesta usando node?

Actualmente estoy intentando de esta manera

```
const {spawn} = require('child_process');

const datos ={//mis datos}

const ssh = spawn(`ssh`,[`${datos.username}@${datos.host}`, `-p${datos.port}`]);

//En este punto me pide la pass pero no hayo como ingresarla, de forma automatica.
//Intente:

process.stdout.write(datos.password);
process.stdout.pipe(ssh.stdin)

//pero no me funciono
```

El por que quiero hacer esto, es basicamente por que quiero conectarme a un conjunto de servidores y ejecutar un comando y guardar esos datos de forma automatica sin tener que hacerlo uno a uno desde la consola.

Comment: ¿Porqué usas `stdout` y no `stdin`?

Comment: tiene razon, aun asi, sigue sin funcionar... al momento de pedir la clave me parece que congela el proceso (parecido a un promt o alert), llevo horas revisando la documentacion y no doy con la respuesta.

Comment: Lamento decirte que no lo lograrás. Los clientes ssh no permiten la lectura de password's desde `stdin`, por lo tanto esta parte no lo podrás automatizar de esta forma. La opción que te queda es usar llaves RSA. Saludos